# How to create local language support on Google Maps using react-native-maps

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

[I wanna to show English and local language support on my React-native-maps like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VudT.jpg),But default it's showing only English,How to make support of bilingual map using react-native-maps

```
<MapView ref={map => {this.map = map}}
      provider={this.props.provider}
      style={styles.map}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      maxZoomLevel={50}
      initialRegion={this.state.region}
      showsBuildings={true}
      onRegionChangeComplete={region => this.onRegion(region)}
    />
```

Comment: It depends on system locale settings, change language from the setting and you will be able to see mapinfo in that language

Comment: I need map in bilingual like how android native is supporting , I attached image with that

Comment: Did u get any solution for this bilingual support throught React Native Maps ?